# Как заставить safari понимать единицы измерения vh, vw

Tags: css, safari

Всем привет. Может, кто посоветует, есть проблемка. На самом первом месте страницы стоит изображение, которое должно занимать всю высоту и ширину экрана. Ширину-то понятно, а вот высоту... Если указывать в vh, то в safari то это не работает! И получается, что изображения вообще нет! Сразу скажу что от контента с paddingами и marginaми изображение вообще не должно зависеть... Есть решение какое-то, чтобы safari сразу понимал эти единицы измерения? Пробовал vminpoly.js, по идее работает, но с этим полифилом чтобы работало, пользователю необходимо изменить размер окна, чтобы со страницей действие какое-либо произошло, тогда он перестраивает страницу и срабатывает, а при начальной загрузке отображает так же криво в safari. Подскажите, если кто знает как решить это?

Comment: какая версия safari?

Comment: c 8 версии safari vh работает - https://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: проверяю работу кода на safari под виндой...стоит версия safari-5-1-7-es-en-fr-de-it-win

Comment: новее просто нет для винды...на ней не работает

Comment: если нужна поддержка этого браузера - вариант через min-height: 100%;

Answer (score 6):

Как выяснилось из комментариев, речь о Сафари под Windows.

Проблема нерешаемая. Не работает, и работать не будет. Продукт официально больше не поддерживается, новые версии не появятся.

Забудьте о существовании Safari под Windows. Ничего общего с современным нативным браузером Safari он уже не имеет.

Answer (score 0):

В конечном итоге нашел решение любых проблем с единицами  vh,vw и так далее, которые не понимаются некоторыми из браузеров(до сей поры). Решение в плагине viewport-units-buggyfill.js. ПОдключаем его, добавляем в конец страницы следующее: 
 window.viewportUnitsBuggyfill.init({
        force: true,
        refreshDebounceWait: 250,
        hacks: window.viewportUnitsBuggyfillHacks
    }); 
И скрипт изменит то, что нужно если будет необходимость.